# How to hide Amazon webstore default toolbar with Prototype?

Tags: animation, prototype, amazon-appstore

after playing around this morning, i've found that there's this default chunk of html code in the amazon webstore which will add a toolbar on top of the page. the html looks like below:

```
    <td id="wba_logo_bg">
<table class="logo" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody><tr><td align="left"></td>
<td class="wba_account" style="padding: 5px;" align="right" valign="top">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<form action="#" id="searchForm" method="get" name="searchForm"></form>
<tbody><tr><td class="wba_account_link">
<a xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="myAccountNav" href="#" onclick="return false;">home</a></td>
<td class="myAccountDots"></td>
<td class="wba_account_link"><a class="myAccountNav" href="#" onclick="return false;">view cart</a></td>
<td class="myAccountDots"></td><td class="wba_account_link"><a class="myAccountNav" href="#" onclick="return false;">my account</a></td>
<td class="myAccountDots"></td><td class="wba_account_link"><a class="myAccountNav" href="#" onclick="return false;">order status</a></td>
<td><img src="pageEditor_files/1_pixel.gif" hspace="7"></td>
<td><input name="keyword" tabindex="1" type="text"></td>
<td><img alt="Search" class="wba_search_btn" onclick="return false;" onkeyup="if (13==event.keyCode) searchForm.submit();" 
src="pageEditor_files/btn_search.gif" style="cursor: pointer;" tabindex="2" title="Search" hspace="3">
</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
</td></tr></tbody>
</table>

</td>
```

and thus far i was able to use prototype to find those with the class name of wba_account_link and hide them via the codes below:

```
    function hideAmazonToolbar()
{
    $("#wba_logo_bg").hide();
}//end function
```

but what i really want to do is preferably to hide the whole tbody instead, but with my limited prototype skills, i don't really know how to do this. can anybody point me to the right resources on how to get this done?

### EDIT

Went higher up and apparently there's a td with an id, and solve it using prototype hide function! man, i love javascript framework :)

Answer (score 1):

You want the [`up`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/up) function. I think this should do it.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('wba_account_link').up('tbody');
```